# SSH - Permission denied (publickey) on server

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, public-key

I am trying to use git on my shared hosting on Hostgator but I am having issues establishing a connection with Github. I already tried tons of answers online but nothing have changed so far.

These are the steps that I followed in order to achieve that (I used [this github guide](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)):

On my machine,

**1.** I made a new key with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "myemail@address.com"`

**2.** I saved it into the file `~/.ssh/remote_github.pub`, the file has no
passphrase

**3.** Then I ran `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

**4.** In my `~/.ssh/config` file I specified

```
Host *
  Hostname IP-ADDRESS-OF-SERVER
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/remote_github
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

**5.** I copied the public key with `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/remote_github.pub` and saved it into my github account

**6.** Then I ran `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/remote_github.pub myuser@remoteserver`

And the answer was

```
INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/Users/mattiabombelli/.ssh/remote_github.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
mbombelli@192.254.233.200's password:
```

After inserting the password:

```
Number of key(s) added:        1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'myuser@remoteserver'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

Checking the `authorized_keys` file on the server I see the same exact public key `remote_github.pub` stored in my machine*

**7.** But at this point, if I try to run `ssh -T -v git@github.com`

This is what I get:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.113.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-c863b32e
debug1: no match: babeld-c863b32e
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home1/mbombelli/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I also made sure to change the permissions on the server with `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` and `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` but the answer is always `Permission denied (publickey).`

What am I doing wrong? Or missing?

Thank you.

*the `authorized_keys` file contains also another `ssh-rsa` public key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if your private key has no passphrase, you don't need anything related to ssh-agent.

Second, "he authorized_keys file on the server I see the same exact public key remote_github.pub stored in my machine*" means you can connect to your server from your local machine.
It has nothing to do with GitHub.

If you want to connect to GitHub from the remote server, then you would need for that remote server account to have your private key.

If you want to connect to GitHub from your local machine, then Hostgator is not involved at all.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I think I was missing the part related to the private key.